# Is there any way to create a system tray app in kivy windows?

Tags: windows, python-2.7, kivy

I know I can do it in win32.gui but I wonder if there is a way with pure kivy.

Comment: I know people have done this before, but it's not built into kivy right now. You might have more luck asking on the mailing list or irc. Although the answer may still be to use win32.gui